# jQuery Parent or Find Method

Tags: jquery, parent

I have a gallery of photos. Each photo has a list that, when formatted with CSS, looks like three large squares (this is my rating system). When the user hovers over the squares, a description is shown below the list. This works great with a single photo but when I hover over the squares for the first photo, the descriptions for ALL photos are displayed.

```
<div class="ratingContainer">
    <ul class="rating">
        <li class="one"></li>
        <li class="two"></li>
        <li class="three"></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="ratingDesc1">Bad</div>
    <div class="ratingDesc2">Normal</div>
    <div class="ratingDesc3">Good</div>
</div>
```

My jQuery...

```
$(".rating li.one").hover(function(){
    $(".ratingDesc1").show();
}, function(){
    $(".ratingDesc1").hide();
});


$(".rating li.two").hover(function(){
    $(".ratingDesc2").show();
}, function(){
    $(".ratingDesc2").hide();
});
```

I have read up on this and it appears I need to use the .parent or .find methods, but all attempts have not worked.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to go up and then back down the DOM:

```
$(".rating li.one").hover(function() {
    $(this).parents('.ratingContainer').find(".ratingDesc1").show();
}, function() {
    $(this).parents('.ratingContainer').find(".ratingDesc1").hide();
});​
```

You could also use a more generic approach and instead of writing separate cases for each rating, use this:

```
$(".rating li").hover(function() {
    $(this).parents('.ratingContainer').find('div:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').show();
}, function() {
    $(this).parents('.ratingContainer').find('div:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').hide();
});​
```

Comment: What about using `$(this).parents('.ratingContainer').find('div').eq($(this).index())` instead?

Comment: @Rocket - unless I'm reading it wrong they're equivalent, no?

Comment: They are the same, but I figured using `.eq` may be easier than using string concatenation (`':eq(' + ...`).

Comment: Thanks everyone - I found this approach to be the best for me. I used the generic example and changed it from $(this).parents('.ratingContainer').find('div:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').show(); to $(this).parents('.ratingContainer').find('div').eq($(this).index()).show() as Rocket suggested. Works like a charm. You are all genius-level in my eyes! Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

to do it in generic method try this

```
$(".rating li").hover(function(){
    $(".ratingDesc:eq(" + $(".rating li").index(this) + ")").show();
}, function(){
    $(".ratingDesc:eq(" + $(".rating li").index(this) + ")").hide();
});
```

Comment: What about using `$(".ratingDesc").eq($(".rating li").index(this))` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse the code instead of hard-coding the names by basing it off of the element's index. I set up a JSFiddle for you to see.

http://jsfiddle.net/3pLr5/6/

Comment: What if he has multiple `ratingContainer`s?

Comment: I have updated it here if he wants to set up multiple ratingContainer's. Basically, I use jquery "closest" to find the parent "ratingContainer". http://jsfiddle.net/3pLr5/7/

Answer (score -1):

View this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hDtJm/), hopefully it's what you're looking for, and a bit more lightweight than your example.

Comment: What if he has multiple `ratingContainer`s?